# Cannot set EPPlus licencing to non commercial without code breaking as 'LicenceContext is a type but being used as a variable' error appears

Tags: c#, excel, winforms, epplus

I am trying to convert text in a label in windows forms to an excel file using EPPlus however when setting the licencing the errors 'LicenceContext is a type but being used as a variable' when

`OfficeOpenXml.LicenseContext = OfficeOpenXml.LicenseContext.NonCommercial;`

is used
ChatGPT suggested

`OfficeOpenXml.LicenseContext = LicenseContext.NonCommercial;`
however there errors 'LicenceContext is a type but being used as a variable' and 'LicenseContext' is an ambiguous reference between 'System.ComponentModel.LicenseContext' and 'OfficeOpenXml.LicenseContext' both appear then.  I am very new to EPPlus and am not sure if there is anything I'm missing

here is the code used

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Drawing;
using System.IO;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Windows.Forms;
using OfficeOpenXml;


namespace Converting_txt_file_to_xlsx
{
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        OpenFileDialog filechooser = new OpenFileDialog();
        
        

        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            
        }

        
        

        private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            if (filechooser.ShowDialog() == DialogResult.OK)
            {
                // Check if the file exists before trying to open it 
                if (File.Exists(filechooser.FileName))
                {
                    // Enclose the StreamReader in a using block to ensure proper closing and disposing
                    using (StreamReader fileReader = new StreamReader(filechooser.FileName, Encoding.UTF8))
                    {
                        string inputrecord = fileReader.ReadToEnd();

                        // Display the content in the TextFile control
                        label1.Text = inputrecord;
                    }
                }
            }


        }

       

        private void btnSaveToExcel_Click_1(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            // Get the text from the label and split it into lines
            string labelText = label1.Text;
            string[] lines = labelText.Split(new string[] { Environment.NewLine }, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries);
            label1.Text = "program started...";
            OfficeOpenXml.LicenseContext = LicenseContext.NonCommercial;

            // Create a new Excel package and add a worksheet
            using (var package = new ExcelPackage())
            {
                var worksheet = package.Workbook.Worksheets.Add("Data");

                // Write each line of text to a separate cell
                for (int row = 1; row <= lines.Length; row++)
                {
                    worksheet.Cells[row, 1].Value = lines[row - 1];
                }

                // Save the Excel file
                string filepath = Path.GetDirectoryName(filechooser.FileName);
                using (var stream = new FileStream("output.xlsx", FileMode.Create))
                {
                    package.SaveAs(stream);
                }
            }

            MessageBox.Show("Text saved to Excel file: output.xlsx");
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Try `ExcelPackage.LicenseContext = LicenseContext.NonCommercial;`